# How to insert image in worksheet title?

Tags: tableau-api

**I want to Image with shape in worksheet title in tableau.**

[image]

same like above image i want to insert image in worksheet title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answer above question..

▬ Nagetive  ▬ % Roll this text put into worksheet title using (ALT+22) character
and color of this text it will shown like bolow image..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your image is a chart legend, to show these on a dashboard simply click onto the drop-down arrow menu on the chart you'd like to see the legend for, and select Legends > then the name of the legend you want to display. This will then appear on the dashboard and you can re-position it however you'd like.